# How to write the set of tuples of consecutive numbers in a set

Tags: notation

I would like to write a sum iterating over 3-tuples of consecutive elements of a set (of floating-point numbers, representing timestamps).

For the moment, my notation is: $\sum\limits_{(t1, t2, t3) \in consecutive_3(T)} f(t1, t2, t3)$

But it gives a quite big index under the sum, so I wonder what shorter but readable notation I could use.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{|T|-2}\;f(t_i,t_{i+1},t_{i+2})$ ?

Comment: @lulu Indeed. Thanks